# passing asp.net mvc model variables to html data attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, variables, custom-data-attribute

What is the best way to pass mvc model variables to html data attribute to create a json attribute.

Basically I want to achieve the below to create the event json

```
    <div class='fc-event' data-event='{"title":"my 
   event","id":8,"taskId":444}'>Hello</div>
```

I want to replace the above static values to variables while in a loop.
The below doesn't work

```
            @if (Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
  <div class='fc-event' data-event= '{"title":@Html.DisplayFor(m => 
   item.Name)}'  > Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

`@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class='fc-event' data-Name="{title:@item.Name,id:@item.Id}">@item.Name</div>
    } 
}`

Comment: thanks the exact syntax was <div class='fc-event' data-event='{"title":"@item.Name","TaskId":@item.Id,"Category":"@item.Category.Name"}'>test</div>. DOUBLE QUOTES FOR STRING AND NONE FOR INT

Answer (score 0):

you could try `data-event='@Json.Encode(item)'`
or build your string like that

```
data-event= '{"title":@Html.Raw(item.title),"id":@Html.Raw(item.title)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.NET to serialize class you need:

```
public class myClass
{
int Id;
string Name;
string CategoryName;
}


myClass simpleExample= new myClass()  
{  
   Id=1,
   Name="Alex",
   CategoryName="Books" 
};  

// Serializing object to json data  
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
string jsonData = js.Serialize(simpleExample); // {"Id":"1","Name":"Alex","CategoryName":"Books"}
```

link with more examples: [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)